# Broken cache? Can't load css on mobile WORDPRESS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, caching

I've made a simple module to paste on WordPress. The thing is, I wanted to show it ONLY on a mobile page. To do this, I used Specific Content for Mobile Version. To make it work, I had to use the W3 Total Cache plugin.

However, I also had to activate LiteSpeed Cache. I made it - but the next day, my client told me, that on the main page (desktop), it shows mobile site.

So I clicked the error: "the page cache add-in file advanced-cache.php is not a w3 total cache drop-in. it should be removed". I changed some CSS, and poof! It doesn't show me the same as `flex-wrap: wrap`.

I attach some photos how it shows me on desktop and how on mobile. Also, I cannot make a backup from yesterday using Updraft.

**It should look like this:**

[image]

**But, it looks like this:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="card-groupp">
 <div class="card col-xs-6">
 <a href="https://amixnutrition.pl/odzywki-bialkowe">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://amixnutrition.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/1.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
 </a>
 <div class="card-body">
 <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://amixnutrition.pl/odzywki-bialkowe">ODŻYWKI BIAŁKOWE</a></h5>
 </div>
 </div>
<div class="card col-xs-6">
<a href="https://amixnutrition.pl/kreatyny">
<img class="card-img-top" src="https://amixnutrition.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/2.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
</a>
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://amixnutrition.pl/kreatyny">KREATYNY</a></h5>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card col-xs-6">
<a href="https://amixnutrition.pl/odzywki-na-mase-gainery">
<img class="card-img-top" src="https://amixnutrition.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
</a>
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://amixnutrition.pl/odzywki-na-mase-gainery">ODŻYWKI NA MASĘ</a></h5>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card col-xs-6">
<a href="https://amixnutrition.pl/witaminy-i-mineraly">
<img class="card-img-top" src="https://amixnutrition.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/4.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
</a>
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://amixnutrition.pl/witaminy-i-mineraly">WITAMINY</a></h5>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card col-xs-6">
<a href="https://amixnutrition.pl/aminokwasy">
<img class="card-img-top" src="https://amixnutrition.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/5.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
</a>
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://amixnutrition.pl/aminokwasy">AMINOKWASY</a></h5>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card col-xs-6">
<a href="https://amixnutrition.pl/promocje">
<img class="card-img-top" src="https://amixnutrition.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/6.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
</a>
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title promocolor"><a href="https://amixnutrition.pl/promocje">PROMOCJE</a></h5>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {

    .product-name a {
        font-size: 12px !important;
    }

    .card {
    width: 50%;
        background-color: #f7f7f7;

}

    .card-img-top {
    width: auto!important;
    }

    .promocolor {
        color:red;
    }
.card-groupp {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
    .card-body {
        padding: 0rem !important;
    }
    .card-title {
        text-align: center;
    }
}

.card-groupp {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

**LOGS FROM BACKUP:**

```
0000.283 () Error message: Nie można przenieść starych plików. Powinieneś sprawdzić właściciela i uprawnienia do plików w twojej instalacji WordPress (/home/topfitco/amix/wp-content/road_tmp)
0000.285 () Restore failed...
0000.285 () Error message: Nie można przenieść starych plików. Powinieneś sprawdzić właściciela i uprawnienia do plików w twojej instalacji WordPress (/home/topfitco/amix/wp-content/road_tmp)
0000.285 () Restore failed
```

[image]

Comment: Did you include css the right way? See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/)

Comment: yep, I added to wordpress css customize panel. The thing i made works on android and doesn't work on Iphone safari...

Comment: Which version of Safari are you using? https://caniuse.com/#search=flex-wrap

Comment: it's not problem with safari bc it worked until i deleted advanced-cache.php ... do you think i should delete all cache plugins(and folder) from ftp?